# Multiple databases in Django - MSSQL

Tags: sql, django, database

i am trying to connect to another MySQL database in django. In default I am using the default LiteSQL which is provided by Django in default settings. I believed that I successfully connected to SQL database, here in settings. So it looks like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },

    'timesheet': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'HOST': '......',
        'NAME': 'Database.department.someview',
        'USER': '....',
        'PASSWORD': '.....',
        'PORT': '.....',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server',
        },
    }
}
```

Know I want to select something in the new database and paste it into view and work with that, like I am using the liteSQL database. Can someone please guide me how to select form this database? Since I am using the default the select looks like `Name-of-model.objects.filter(id=deletesignificantaccountid)` but I do not know how I should name the model, cause I don't have it in models. So can someone help me with that? The database will be used only for read, I do not and I cannot write in it.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to achieve two things:

1. Use several databases
2. Use an existing database to create and use models

Is that right?

1. Your line of code is correct, but you need to add `using("timesheet")` [doc here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/multi-db/#manually-selecting-a-database)
2. You still need to have models to create python objects, otherwise django would not know what to do with the SQL result. doc about using legacy database [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/legacy-databases/)

Comment: 1. Yes
2. I want to use both databases. The new one only for select

2. "You still need to have models to create python objects, otherwise django would not know what to do with the SQL result. doc about using legacy database" - this means I will just make in my models new class where I will define the columns which I have in the new database and set this. db_table = 'timesheet' and it will work fine right ?

Comment: `db_table` is the name of the table representing the model in your MSSQL server.
To use the `timesheet` db when reading this specific model, you can use a db router with the `db_for_read` method  as defined [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/multi-db/#db_for_read)